# Hide files in eclipse navigator

Tags: eclipse

I love to use the Navigator view in Eclipse. I know most people are like "ahhh Project Explorer or riot!!" but really I like Navigator and I'm able to get work done with it.

I recently imported a git project. And it shows the .gitkeep files in the Navigator window.

I want them gone.

I've googled, I've searched menus, I just can't find a way to do it. I turned off all `.*` files in the mean time, but I'd really like to define my own filter.

A couple nuggets of wisdom I found:

1. You can do it but "not without coding" - okay, well I am a developer - coding what? is it hard?
2. "That's what working sets are for" - it appears working sets just let me assign what files to keep - I don't want to have to go through every folder, and ignore this file every time. I want to one-and-done it.
3. Is this possibly a git setting? I see a "hideDotFiles" setting but I don't know what to put there to make it work.

I'm pretty desperate. It shouldn't bother me, but it does. How can I make this stupid file disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be pretty easy.

Follow [these instructions](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-97.htm) and add an `Exclude all` filter for `Files` whose `Name` `matches` `.gitkeep`.

> - To create a resource filter:
> - In one of the navigation views, right-click the project or folder where you want to create the resource filter.
> - From the pop-up menu, select *Properties*. The properties dialog will open.
> - Expand the *Resource* section.
> - Click the *Resource Filters* section.
> - Click *Add...*.
> - Specify the filter type, to what entries it applies to, and enter the condition.
> - Click *OK*.
> - Click *OK*.

Comment: That certainly did it! I was hoping I could make it `.git*` or something but that didn't seem to work. So if other .git files come up I'll just add them. I'll have to do this project by project, but still it should work out, since they don't seem to come up often. Excelllllent.